# Connecting transformation to Blendshape Weight SparkAR

Tags: javascript, c++, augmented-reality

I am testing JavaScript to achieve some form of automation.

Project is to have Animation keyframes get exported from Maya in the form of translateY. Now I get the fbx imported in Spark and I would like to connect these keyframe values into deformation in SparkAR. Does anyone know how I can achieve that? I have got all the info from the blend shapes and it’s index and also values. I just can’t figure out how to connect it. I don’t want to do it in Patch but the only JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Load modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Reactive = require('Reactive');
const Animation = require('Animation');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

const timeDriver = Animation.timeDriver({durationMilliseconds: 5000});

Scene.root.findFirst('Blue_Body').then(function(body) {
    Diagnostics.watch("Name - ", body.name);
    const blendshapeCount = body.blendShapes.count;
    //Diagnostics.log(blendshapeCount);

    //for (let i=0; i<blendshapeCount; i++){
    for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
        const blendshapeMesh = body.blendShapes.getAtIndex(i);
        const blendshapeName = blendshapeMesh.name;
        const blendshape = blendshapeMesh.weight.lastValue;
        Scene.root.findFirst(blendshapeName).then(function(shape){
            const transform = shape.transform;
            // Here I need to set blendshapeMesh.weight = transform.y, HOW TO DO THIS?
            Diagnostics.watch(blendshapeName, blendshapeMesh.weight.lastValue);
            Diagnostics.watch(shape.name, transform.y);
        });
    }

});
```

[Console Image with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaDTj.png)

Comment: Can you share some example fbx. Haven't played with blendshapes?